# Сортировка стека вставкой (псевдокод - Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, стек, псевдокод

Необходимо написать функцию сортировки стека вставкой на Python, используя исходный псевдокод:

```
// Сортируем элементы в стеке.
StackInsertionsort(Stack: items)
// Создаем временный стек.
Stack: temp_stack = New Stack
Integer: num_items = <количество элементов>
For i = 0 To num_items - 1
    // Ищем позицию следующего элемента.
    // Забираем первый элемент.
    Data: next_item = items.Pop()
    <Переносим еще не отсортированные элементы
    во временный стек temp_stack. На этом этапе у нас
    (num_items - i - 1) неотсортированных элементов.>
    <Перемещаем отсортированные элементы во второй стек,
    пока не найдем место для next_item.>
    <Добавляем next_item в эту позицию.>
<Возвращаем элементы из временного стека temp_stack в исходный.> Next i
End StackInsertionsort
```

На данный момент получился такой код на Python:

```
#сортировка элементов в стеке
def StackInsertionsort(items):
#создать временный стек
    temp_stack = Stack()
    num_items = len(Stack())
    for i in range(0, num_items - 1):
        next_item = items.pop()
        temp_stack.push(#?)
        #???
        temp_stack.push(next_item)
        items.push(temp_stack.pop())
```

Соответственно, вопросам помечены непонятные мне места реализации кода, заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Если честно, я не уверен что ваш алгоритм на псевдокоде корректен. И он какой-то нестрогий. Я так и не понял, что конкретно там нужно реализовывать. Вопросы уже в начале цикла - вообще не ясно, почему есть гарантия, что мы уложимся за <количество элементов> итераций. У задачки сортировки стека посредством вспомогательного стека есть вполне себе классическое решение. Если хотите, я могу его привести и постараюсь объяснить, но это не вполне то, что описывает ваш псевдокод.

Comment: Мне бы очень помогло, заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Окей, давайте попробуем сделать это правильно, попутно я постараюсь пояснить, что в вашем псевдокоде не так.

Сперва сам алгоритм: идея в том, чтобы завести второй стек, элементы в котором будут отсортированы между итерациями. В конце работы он будет содержать все элементы исходного в отсортированном порядке.

1. Снимаем с верхушки исходного стека элемент `x`.
2. Находим позицию, в которую его можно добавить во временный стек, такую, чтобы не нарушался инвариант. Эта позиция - либо единственно возможная, если временный стек пуст, либо сразу после элемента, который больше `x`, ибо тогда ниже в стеке окажутся элементы меньшие или равные (напоминаю, временный стек всегда отсортирован). Для того, чтобы `x` поместить в эту позицию, мы последовательно вынимаем из стека все, что нам мешает, и кладем в исходный стек (позже мы все равно это отсортируем). (строчки 2 и 3)
3. Помещаем `x` во временный стек. Временный стек остается отсортирован после этого шага. (строчка 4)
4. Повторяем до тех пор, пока в исходном стеке не осталось элементов. (строчка 1)

При особенно сильном желании вернуть именно исходный стек всегда в конце можно вынуть все элементы из временного и поместить в исходный, предварительно переделав сравнение.

```
def sort_stack(s):
    t = []                            
    while s:                          # (1)
        x = s.pop()
        while t and t[-1] > x:        # (2)
            s.append(t.pop())         # (3)
        t.append(x)                   # (4)
    return t
```

Надо сказать, что пока я писал ответ, я наконец понял, что написано в вашем псевдокоде. Дело в том, что инвариант у вас совершенно другой - на каждой i-той итерации первые i элементов стэка будут отсортированными. Я считаю этот подход плохим, потому как он более сложен для понимания. Но тем не менее, давайте напишем решение по вашему псевдокоду:

```
def sort_stack2(s):
    t = []
    t2 = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        x = s.pop()
        for _ in range(len(s) - i):
            t.append(s.pop())
        while s and s[-1] > x:
            t2.append(s.pop())
        s.append(x)
        while t2:
            s.append(t2.pop())
        while t:
            s.append(t.pop())
    return s
```

Временный стек тут у нас `t`, а 'второй', как у вас в псевдокоде - `t2`. В принципе, вы можете проследить соответствие один-к-одному моего кода и вашего псевдокода. В целом это, конечно, работает, и по сути, time complexity у обоих вариантов - O(n^2), memory complexity - O(n); но ваш вариант гораздо сложнее для понимания - очень много ненужного перекладывания элементов туда-сюда, и две временные структуры данных. Это видно даже по размеру кода.

Понимание, почему именно это работает, можно получить, поиграв с дебаггером - причем я вам настоятельно советую поиграть с обеими вариантами алгоритмов.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, очень помогло, все понял и во всем разобрался!)

Answer (score 0):

Стек представлен с помощью массива и функций `append` (добавление в стек) и `pop` (снятие со стека).
Цикл `while temp_stack` работает, пока в `temp_stack` есть элементы. Ветка `if not found` работает, когда место для элемента `next_item` не найдено (`next_item` оказался больше тех элементов, которые уже отсортированы и находились в `temp_stack` перед началом сравнения). `range(num_items)` принимает значения от `0` до `num_items - 1` включительно.

```
def StackInsertionsort(items):
    temp_stack = []
    num_items = len(items)
    for i in range(num_items):
        for _ in range(i):
            temp_stack.append(items.pop())
        next_item = items.pop()
        found = False
        while temp_stack:
            temp_item = temp_stack.pop()
            if not found and next_item < temp_item:
                found = True
                items.append(next_item)
                temp_stack.append(temp_item)
            else:
                items.append(temp_item)
        if not found:
            items.append(next_item)

items = [3,1,2,5,4,7,0]
StackInsertionsort(items)
print(items)
# Результат:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Это не тот алгоритм, который описан в вопросе.